# Deploying a .NET application to Google Cloud Platform worked on initial deploy, now getting 502 Error: Server Error

Tags: html, .net, google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2016, netcoreapp2.1

To give some background, I'm an (unpaid) intern, and I'm unrelated to dealing with this kind of stuff. My employers wanted to update some pictures, and they did locally but didn't know how to upload the new version to the server.

I used the publish settings that were saved in Visual Studio from when the previous intern deployed the server (he was specialized in web site stuff) and it worked on deploy ... then I refreshed the page and I'm getting 502 server error.

Steps I have taken:

1. Connect to the VM and restart it - didn't solve it. it's using Microsoft server 2016.
2. Open the VM trough RDP, check if there are errors. There were 3 services not running, and I start them manually. One still isn't running, Downloaded Maps Manager. Ok... I google it and it's not a necessary service so I disable it. Now there are no errors and all services are running but I still am getting this error.
3. I tried pinging the IP of the server, and the URL itself and it works.

I believe it might be something to do with the load balancer, but I had one HTML class and nothing dealing with actually publishing stuff. If you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. The only reason why I'm trying to fix this myself is that I didn't make some kind of backup, and I feel so stupid having taken the site down.

Edit: I've gone to "load balancing" and it says service unhealthy. I tried going to the IPs there and it brings me to the same 502 server error page. From what I've gathered this is a configuration error, it's impossible they messed something with the site itself, right? It did work that first time, and if I run it from Visual Studio it works on the local machine ...

Comment: 502 often means that your browser is talking to server 1 (which could be a proxy), which then makes a request to server 2 (which in this case is likely your web server). For some reason, server 2 returns a "bad" reply, that server 1 does not understand or that server 1 is configured to hide from you. The only way to find out what is happening is to try to look at what server 2 is doing, e.g. by looking at log files, or (using RDP) by opening the Event Log tool from Windows.

Comment: I'll do that now. Just as a log of what I'm doing, I restarted the server again, and now 2 services aren't running: Web Deployment Agent Service and Sync Host_974b0.
I'm going to manually start these.

Yes, there are 10 errors in the past hour when looking at the event viewer. 4 in perflib, 2 in service control manager, 3 in distributed COM.

Guess I gotta start googling stuff again :)

Comment: Is the web server home page accessible in a web browser on the Windows server itself?